# Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error ngRoute 1.4.8

Tags: angularjs, razor, ngroute, ng-sortable

I am trying to get a drag drop list to run in my project, I have a bare bones example in my cshtml file. But before I even get there I get a injector module error. Even if i specifically add the ngRoute to my layout page i still get the error. My app.js looks like the following.

If i remove the 'as.sortable' then it works fine except the drag drop doesn't work. If i add it i get the injector error.

```
   var appModule = angular.module("app", [
        "ui.bootstrap",
        'ui.utils',
        "ui.jq",
        'ui.grid',
        'ui.grid.pagination',
        "oc.lazyLoad",
        "ngSanitize",
        'angularFileUpload',
        'daterangepicker',
        'ngRoute',
        'as.sortable'
    ]);
```

Scipt included in html as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/node_modules/ng-sortable/dist/ng-sortable.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/node_modules/ng-sortable/dist/ng-sortable.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/node_modules/ng-sortable/dist/ng-sortable.style.min.css">
```

Comment: have you added the `<script>` tag for ng-sortable to your HTML?

Comment: yes, sorry just updated the post to say i have that included